# Recent high seismic activity in Europe

Tags: earthquakes, seismic

It seems that Europe and the Mediterranean Sea have had high seismic activity in last six months. Major events which I remember are:

- 2020 Aegean Sea earthquake, magnitude of 7.0  Mww
- 29 December 2020:  Petrinja, Croatia, magnitude 6.4 earthquake
- Many Etna volcano eruptions
- 3 March 2021: Týrnavos, Greece  6.3  Mww
- Many earthquakes in recent weeks in Iceland and an alert for volcanic eruption
- Today (18 March 2021): 6.0 Mww earthquake in souther Mediterranean Sea, near Béjaïa, Algeria

What could this high seismic activity across Europe tell us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice tracker for global earthquake activity at https://www.volcanodiscovery.com/earthquakes/global-seismic-activity-level.html, although it doesn't conveniently allow you to look at regional statistics, as opposed to global or national records.

At a global level there doesn't seem to be any particular increase in events , although in a quasi random series clustering in time and space isn't unexpected.

The perception that there might be an increase is probably a reflection of human and media behaviour; when one event occurs it heightens our interest and the likelihood of noticing other events. The media are far more likely to report a small earthquake occurring in the immediate aftermath of a large earthquake elsewhere in the world, than they would have if it had occurred in isolation.

Comment: And you can look at the individual mentions: Greek EQs of M6 are pretty normal - so much so, they'd only raise an eyebrow from me if they were >7.2 or so.  Etna is one of the most active volcanoes near significant population. It would be more news-worthy if it was quiet for 5+ years. And are we seeing the same eruption? (I would say yes)  Iceland gets a volcanic eruption every ~2 yrs or so - you only hear about them when international air travel is disrupted, or the tabloids are bored of scaring people with immigrants and switch to volcanoes for a day or two (see also, Yellowstone).